# How do I create a hyperlink with only one word in Pages?

Tags: macos, hyperlink, iwork-pages

I use Pages.app on OS X Leopard to create a monthly newsletter.

- How do I create a link to a URL using only one word, such as "Garden" linking to a gardeners page?
- I have exhausted all graphics in Pages and even pulled in graphics contained in iWeb and Keynote for added interest. It works just fine. Any suggestions on where I can pull new material from? Would have thought there would have been a Pages update by now. I am '09.

Answer (score 0):

Select the word, and in the Inspector, click the *Link* tab. Here, check *Enable as a hyperlink* and add your link.

[image]

As far as I know, Apple doesn't provide additional graphics or templates – and currently, there is no new version of iWork released. You'll find plenty of (commercial) Pages templates online though.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one or any words hyperlinks using ⌘ + K shortcut (Command + K).

There is a newest Pages update. Since 2013 it's being updated through Mac App Store. Current version is 5.5.3, released on April 21, 2015. [More info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pages_(word_processor)#Version_history).